# Are individual securities transactions archived by the U.S. government?

Tags: united-states, security, historical-data, research

I'm looking for documentation of historical security trades (buys and sells) and am wondering if there is a U.S. government agency that maintains archives of individual transactions.

If so, how long are the records maintained?

Answer (score 2):

No. Why would the US government even care? The exchanges might want to archive their transaction history for a certain period, brokers also, but the US government? No.